# Q: Rails Best Practices for database calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Quick question. I am building out a portfolio application for an artist, currently have 9 tables of different types of projects (exhibitions, press, news, texts, photography, etc). As a visual artist, he wants his site to represent his vision.

**Background:**

**edit**: The information is loaded from the controller originally, not from an API call. I later changed it to an API call because I was worried 9 calls from the controller was too much.

This means the site is graphic and information heavy. Loading all the information **just for the navigation** was 15 mb (and this was after shrinking the images when needed and running them through tinypng). I put all the information off to different layout views to be rendered only when needed to keep loading times down and offset it, which helped speed everything. But this setup no matter which way resulted in 9 different database calls on each page load.

I rebuilt the back end to API endpoints, so the information is only pulled from the database when needed. This has slightly increased the load time for the information though, only like a second more if that. I'm not bothered by it, but the artist might be.

**Actual Question**

So I've been wondering for the past few days, is 9 database calls too much at once and how will it affect scalability? Postgres database for reference. Normal load, I cant imagine too many users will view the site on any given time, so I wouldnt be worried about it. But when he has an exhibition and there are 100-500 people using the site at once, thats 900-4500 database calls each page load. Or with the API route, people may only do 1 or 2 calls before finding what they want. I just want to follow the industry best practice for handling this situation and this seemed like a good time to ask this question.

Also, this will be hosted on heroku currently, and wondering which way (all at once or API routes) will be better for handling postgres connections since the free tier (which will be enough 95% of the time) has a limit of 20 connections. Though for months where he has a show we could bump it up to the next tier for 60 connections.

Comment: When the page loads for the first time, how long do each of these API calls take? Nine doesn't seem like a lot to me, but it sounds like each call might be downloading quite a bit of data?

Comment: @quicklikerabbit So, i added an edit incase it wasnt clear. With the original 9 calls, that was from the application controller, it wasnt an API call. The page right now takes 1.19-1.63 seconds for me to load (before it starts loading images on the home screen). So all 9 calls are now complete. For the API version, the dom loads in <1 second, and the API calls take at most 200ms to load (no throttling), but as long as 96ms. But then images will start loading*

Comment: It sounds like you'd benefit from looking into caching of images, and using a CDN. Unless you started getting a serious n+1 database calls problem then postgresql is going to be the highest performing part of your system.

Comment: Okay, will do thanks @DavidAldridge

Answer (score 0):

What you describe doesn't sound like a dynamic website. Unless it has an admin section to modify the content, there is really little reason to keep the data in a DB or use a web "application" like Rails.

I would suggest to use a Ruby static site generator. [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) is the most popular one, but I recommend [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) because it makes it very easy to migrate from Rails view templates and helpers.

If you really want to use Rails, then yours is a textbook use case for view caching. If the content is static there is no reason to load it over and over again with each page view.

Also, nine DB queries per page views doesn't mean much. It could be little or it could be a lot, it really depends on the queries.

Comment: There is an admin section. Whenever a new work is added I wanted it to be as easy as possible for the artist to update the page so I wrote a CMS backend for it, which is why I have the content loading dynamically instead of static.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post about Rails [Database Best Practices](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2016/11/16/rails-database-best-practices/?utm_source=dbweekly&utm_medium=email).

Without knowing too much about your application, see if you can reduce the number of database calls with scopes and/or query objects. Combining calls with a `.includes()` or `.join()` is a way to reduce the load as well. See if the data can be aggregated with `.group()` or `.having()`. If each call is necessary, then you can potentially increase the speed of the query by introducing some indexing.

From my experience, I wouldn't say there's an industry standard for the maximum number of database calls a page load should have; it really depends on the data being returned.

Comment: Okay thank you! I just didnt want to one day find the site is having issues because he had an art exhibit and 500 people were trying to use this site all at once, and the database slowed down or worse because too many hits all at once that it wasnt optimized for. But if its more about the content that is being loaded rather than the hits, then I'm less worried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I've been dealing with a lot of issues regarding optimisation and I'll give some of my own suggestions:

- serve all static assets through a CDN - unless you really know what you're doing let the CDN handle caching
- you mention it has a built in CMS for it - version all images uploaded into different sizes, so you can optimise display through versioning (thumbs for thumbs, midsize (max-width 1920<->3840) for everything else and only save/use bigger than those sizes if really needed)
- understand JPG compression - you can lower it from the usual 100% to around 70% (this does depend on the actual images) without loosing any meaningful information - this is non rails related, and should be done as step on optimising all image content
- for optimising the images added through the CMS you can use RMagick or Minimagick. In RMagick you have access to self.quality when processing images - unless images have transparencies always convert to JPG & quality down to 70<->80%
- cache the queries to the db themselves - [heroku caching](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching-ruby-rails)

I personally use a technique to load the images only after html rendering

```
function loadPortfolios() {
  var collections = $(".profile_collection");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  var image;
  $.each(collections, function () {
    image = $(this).data('source');
    imageObj.src = image;
    $(this).css({ backgroundImage: 'url('+image+')', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: "cover", backgroundPosition: 'center' });
  });
  $.each($('.image_portfolio, .hover_image'), function() {
    imageObj.src=$(this).data('url');
  });
}
```

This works by having data attributes in the types of "portfolio". So once the website is loaded and JS ready fired, this function gets called. Instantiating a JS Image object (`new Image()`), followed by attributing a url to the `.src` attribute makes it start loading the images. I haven't benchmarked it yet, but will soon - not sure it really plays a part but if you try it let me know. The reason why I use this this way is because it's more important for me to reduce the number of requests for external elements, in order to load the JS, so that the website is functional the soonest possible. And then start getting the images.

I'm sure there's plenty of other optimisations that could be done.
EDIT:

If you're getting bogged down on the database queries as well, look at the amount of helper methods you're using both in the controller and views (when you load a lot of stuff it can really render things slower). Then look at how you're querying things. Some examples could help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. 

Someone also mentioned the CDN so since I'm using AWS for images I'll check out cloudfront, so thank you. Also, the images are already optimized and sized, but thanks for that as well. I've constantly been drilling myself to be better about site load speed (hence the questions) so that was always something I've been sure to do.

Comment: Cloudfront is great. I've been using it myself and it really speeds up compared to serving directly from s3. Most of this was actually related to the contents you're serving and not the database queries themselves. I haven't gotten so deep yet on my own research simply because I haven't got the need for it yet. If you have any samples of what you would like to optimise provide them, best